How to call an JFrog Artifactory user plugin executions
I have an artifactory cluster with two nodes
I call the plugin as folows:
curl -L -X POST 'https://my-artifactory.com/artifactory/api/plugins/execute/myPlugin?params=repos=docker;packagetypes=docker' \
-H 'Authorization: Bearer <your token>

Excerpt of plugin code
executions {
    myPlugin(version: '1.0', description: 'Do some specifitc stuff', groups: [''].toSet()) { params ->

 log.info("Plugin Execution started")

}

The problem now is that the log entry appears twice what simply means that the plugin is executed two times.
